# SAX Parser Script for DOM Parser in PHP

Tags: php, dom, sax

I need the **SAX** parser code for my **DOM** Document code.

If anybody would be kind enough to provide me the code for the same.

```
 function flipkart_price_fetch($sel_image){  
    global $sel_image;  
    $price = file_get_contents("{$sel_image['flipkart_content']}");  
    $dom = new DOMDocument();  
    @$dom->loadHTML($price);  
    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');  
    foreach($divs as $div){  
        if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'fk-font-verybig pprice fk-bold'){  
            echo $div->nodeValue;  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you would need to use SAX?

Comment: I have used DOM here and it is taking a heck lot of time to parse.. so I googled it and found that SAX parser is more faster than DOM. I need to get the results faster on my webpage.. what do u suggest instead?

Comment: I use DOM+Xpath mostly. XMLReader for really large XML files, but DOM+Xpath again for the parts. I am not sure that SAX or XMLReader can even handle HTML.

Comment: Sir, can you please provide your solution to this code to parse it faster.. I am in dying need to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DOM is the performance hog here, but the iteration of all `span` element nodes. DOMXpath allows to use Xpath expressions to fetch nodes directly:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($sel_image['flipkart_content']);  
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// this matches the node by the class name "pprice"
$price = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(.//span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " pprice ")])'
);

echo $price;
```

Search SO and/or the Web for Xpath.

You have some additional errors in your source:

1. `global $sel_image;`

   `$sel_image` is the function argument, here no reason to make it a global state.
2. `"{$sel_image['flipkart_content']}"`

   This string contains only the variable, use the variable directly `$sel_image['flipkart_content']` or cast it to a string `(string)$sel_image['flipkart_content']`
3. $price = file_get_contents("{$sel_image['flipkart_content']}");

   Here is no need to load the file/url separately - use `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.. I have made $sel_image global because i have also used it somewhere else in my other code.. Regarding the errors 2 and 3, I will make sure of that.. :)